# InnoSetup can't find 'My Documents' on Win XP installed on Mac Parallels

Tags: windows, inno-setup, special-folders, parallels

I'm stuck trying to help a user install our software. Our software setup is distributed using InnoSetup, and he is installing it on a Mac Pro with Parallels and Windows XP. During installation, InnoSetup fails with:

`Internal error: Failed to expand shell folder constant "userdocs"`

In InnoSetup, {userdocs} maps to the 'My Documents' folder, and as InnoSetup is written in Delphi, I assume it uses CSIDL_Personal or CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS to retrieve this folder, but I don't know how to fix these locations.

Anyone encountered this before? If so, do you know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved: after user insisting that their installation of XP was working fine, it became clear that their specified "My Documents"  folder doesn't exist! I've suggested they need to reinstall XP, but also passed along MSalter's suggestion of using TweakUI to change the folder location to one that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve such problems on XP, use [TweakUI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe) from XP PowerToys.

Comment: To change expected Location of My Documents folder